# how to call a javascript function from an included javascript file using GWT?

Tags: gwt

I have a function Load() in a js file which I added to the GWT module.

I am trying to call it using

```
private static native void load() /*-{
   $doc.Load();
}-*/;
```

but it gives me error like

Error(s) occurred! (TypeError): $doc.Load is not a function fileName: http://localhost:8888/myapp/888C05FB242806B071A932498F6B5AD9.cache.html lineNumber: 1224

I even tried with $wnd.Load()

What the proper way of calling it?

Comment: What do you mean by "I added to the GWT module"? You can just include the js file in your host page via a `<script>` tag and then the `$wnd.Load()` reference should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Igor is correct. Consider the following snippet from the host HTML file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/gxt-all.css" />
    <script language="JavaScript">
    function dostuff() {
        alert("Stuff is being done.");
    }
    </script>

    <!--                                                               -->
    <!-- Consider inlining CSS to reduce the number of requested files -->
    <!--                                                               -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="GxtSandbox.css">
```

And the following snippet from GWT code:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    doGwtStuff();
}

public native void doGwtStuff() /*-{
    $wnd.dostuff();
}-*/;
```

This alert is shown.